# Flutter - bottom sheet how to move textfield to the bottom

Tags: flutter

I want TextField to show at the bottom of the screen.

```
return Column(
      children: [
        const _Title(),
        Stack(
          children: [
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: const [
                _Message(),
              ],
            ),
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter a search term',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
```

[image]

If I put Wrap my Textfield Widget in a position bottom:0  I get a hasSize error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Wrap the `Stack` with an `Expanded` widget so that it takes the full vertical available space.

Then, wrap the `TextField` with a `Positioned` and in addition to setting `bottom` to zero, you need to set the `left` and `right` to whatever value you want.

```
return Column(
    children: [
      const _Title(),
      Expanded(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: const [
                _Message(),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: const TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with align

```
Column(
            children: [
              const _Title(),
              Flexible(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: const [
                        _Message()
                      ],
                    ),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

Comment: I get this error. The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#100ee NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderViewport#100ee NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    needs compositing
    parentData: <none> (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=342.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)

Comment: @Millenial2020 please check, i updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the height after wrapping the Column widget with a container.

```
return Container( 
height: 80, // add here height of your container, hope it will work. 
child: Column(
      children: [
        const _Title(),
        Stack(
          children: [
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: const [
                _Message(),
              ],
            ),
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Enter a search term',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this? .Its working I have tested.

```
return Column(
      children: [
         const _Title(),,
        Stack(
          children: [
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: const [
                _Message(),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Spacer(),
        const TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            hintText: 'Enter a search term',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```